# How to use split text to column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, split

I want to split text in column:

[image]

This is link to my spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uSgHy_RR2Yk30eP0zq-K9W2f4_JgcuiEMDHGA-yQrRg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula. See you google-sheet.

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A2:A4,", ")&"@"&B2:B4&"@"&C2:C4),"@")),"where Col3 is not null")
```

[image]

Comment: =QUERY(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A2:A4,", ")&"@"&B2:B4&"@"&C2:C4),"@")),"where Col3 is not null"). When i use this formula in new sheet, i have error. How to use this formula on new sheet?

Comment: Check your sheet now.

Comment: Sir Harun24hr can u check my Q2, how to fix "query return and empty column" WHEN have date column.